# How can I get Pull Request details using the octokit js client?

Tags: github, octokit-js

When trying to get the details for a specific pull request (via a call to `ocktokit.pulls.get`, I get the error "Resource not accessible by integration".  Doing the exact same thing for an issue (`octokit.issues.get`) works as expected.  I'm using the `createAppAuth` authorization strategy:

```
const octokit = new Octokit({
  authStrategy: createAppAuth,
  auth: {
    id: APP_ID,
    privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
    installationId: INSTALLATION_ID,
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
})
```

Authorization can't be the issue since I can get details for a (non-PR) issue.  How can I get details for a pull request?